# Algolia: How do I add (is it possible) to add a numeric disjunctive refinement?

Tags: algolia

On my DB, I store an expiration date for each record. Some records do not expire (are active forever), this records have a `null` expiration date.

So the logic for -say- a SQL statement to get records that should be shown, would be:

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE expires > NOW() OR expires IS NULL;
```

To get these records in Algolia, I'm currently using this:

```
helper.addNumericRefinement('expires', '>=', moment().utc().startOf('day').unix());
```

Which is leaving the `expires = null` records out, and I want them IN.

I'm trying to save myself a cron script that would remove all expired items from Algolia every night. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely doable.

Unfortunately Algolia doesn't support refinements on `NULL` values. So first of all you'll need to update your indexing script and cast `NULL` values into integer or string. In your case I'd go probably for `-1` instead of `NULL`.

Then you can set query parameter `filters` to the helper:

```
helper.setQueryParameter('filters','expires = -1 OR expires >= ' + current_time);
```

It'll do the trick. I created a small jsFiddle for you to see it live: https://jsfiddle.net/tdkxnuyn/

Right now [Algolia Helper JS](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/) doesn't use `filters` parameter for it's high level methods (like `addFacetRefinement`, `addNumericRefinement`, ...) so it's safe to use in `setQueryParameter`. But it may change in future so be careful when updating the version of the helper.